# Can I update the composer including the suggested libraries

Tags: php, composer-php

Can I update the composer including the suggested libraries, something like this:

```
composer update --include-suggests
```

Comment: Packages that were suggested to you when installing another package are not installed. What do you expect such a command to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested packages are simply advertising. They emit a message after updating or installing packages to notify you of the fact that you may get more functionality by adding more packages that work well together with the ones already installed.

They are not installed yet. You'd have to decide that you actually need the features they offer, and actively install them. After that, such a package will not be mentioned in the suggested package list, and will be affected by `composer update` just like any other package.